# Saving data to database without using a form tag

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post

I am very new to web programming. I took an online course covering html, css, js and node, now I started to build an online calendar application. In my calendar page each day of the year is represented by a text input. So there are 365 inputs in the page. What I am trying to do is; when an input lost focus, the value of the input must be stored in a mongo database. I assume that I should send a post request to my index.js file from the calendar.ejs file when the input lost focus. But all the examples I could find so far use form tag. Is it possible to send a post request when the onfocusout event of a text input is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery $.ajax?

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.your-url.com",
        type: "POST",
        data: { ... } // payload to the api
    }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //your code
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(
                "The following error occurred: " +
                textStatus, errorThrown
                );
    }).always(function () {
        // your code
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It really worked! I am so happy now :)